# Are `redux-loop` and `connected-react-router` compatible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, connected-react-router, redux-loop

I have made a simple react app with the sample code from the following blogpost, which I leave only as a citation. I am otherwise new to the javascript ecosystem and am trying to fit together several unfamiliar tools (in order to learn them).

https://medium.com/@notrab/getting-started-with-create-react-app-redux-react-router-redux-thunk-d6a19259f71f

Relevantly, my `store.js` looks like this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, } from 'redux';
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware, } from 'connected-react-router';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { install, } from 'redux-loop';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import rootReducer from './modules';

export const history = createHistory();

const initialState = {};
const middleWare = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history),];

const composedEnhancers = compose(
  applyMiddleware(...middleWare),
  install()
);

const store = createStore(
  connectRouter(history)(rootReducer),
  initialState,
  composedEnhancers
);

export default store;
```

This seems to work fine, and the `Link`/`Route` triggers on my page work fine. Note that `install` from `redux-loop` is being called as part of an enhancer (?) and this is fine. I do not have any `loop` calls in my reducers, I just inserted the `install` command as an enhancer with the hope that I will be able to add some.

Here is my main `reducer` code:

```
import { combineReducers, } from 'redux';
import counter from './counter';
import todo from './todo';

export default combineReducers({
  counter,
  todo,
});
```

Again, this works great. However, if I insert `loop` anywhere in my reducers, it dies. According to the docs, this is because we need to use the `combineReducers` from `redux-loop`. Fine. If I replace the import at the top to `import { combineReducers, } from 'redux-loop';` (not altering my reducers at all, there are no nonstandard returns yet) then I get some completely nonsensical errors in library code:

```
ConnectedRouter.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined
    at ConnectedRouter.js:58
    at Object.dispatch (redux.js:221)
    at dispatch (install.js:66)
    at middleware.js:25
    at index.js:11
    at Object.onLocationChanged (ConnectedRouter.js:154)
    at handleLocationChange (ConnectedRouter.js:85)
    at new ConnectedRouter (ConnectedRouter.js:94)
    at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:11769)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:13491)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:14090)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:16416)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:16454)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:16533)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:17387)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:17295)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:17267)
    at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:17155)
    at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:16949)
    at scheduleRootUpdate (react-dom.development.js:17637)
    at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:17664)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:17691)
    at ReactRoot../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render (react-dom.de...
```

It goes on for many pages, but the issue seems to be in `ConnectedRouter`; I assume this is because `combineReducers` in `redux-loop` changes the response type of the main reducer into something that's not compatible with the `connectRouter(history)(rootReducer)` in the `createStore` call.

Is this the right issue? Is this fixable? Can these two libraries be used together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/79) that would address this, but until that is done it requires a hack. I called combineReducers with something like this (I am using immutable js. but if you're not it's simple to convert to that)

```
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router/immutable';
import { Map } from 'immutable';

//....

const routerReducer = connectRouter(history)(() => fromJS({}));
return combineReducers(
  {
    foo: fooReducer,
    blah: blahReducer,
    router: (state, action) => {
      const routerStateWrapper = Map({router: state});
      const result = routerReducer(routerStateWrapper, action);
      return result.get('router');
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: This worked great for me. I'd love if they had a nice fix, but this is perfectly clean enough for me!

Comment: looks like they have a PR open to address this https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/pull/140

Answer (score 1):

It's already supported in v5+.

Release note: https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/releases/tag/v5.0.0
PR: https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/pull/150